# Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL v8.0 "Missing type info or binding"

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

I updated my program to dotnet 8 and then updated Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL from v 7.0~ to 8.0.

Below is an example of the code it worked fine in v7.0 and I got the error Missing type info or binding in v 8.0. Googling I found this https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/5428. Does this just mean it's a bug and I have to wait for 8.01 to come out for it to be fixed?

In the meantime, I have downgraded Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL back to v7~ so that it works again.

```
var batchcommand = new NpgsqlBatchCommand($@"
       INSERT INTO example_table (id, column1, column2)
       VALUES (@id, @value1, @value2)
       ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET 
           column1 = excluded.column1, 
           column2 = excluded.column2
   ");
   

   
  
   batchcommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar) { Value = id });
   batchcommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@value1", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric) { Value = value1 });
   batchcommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@value2", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric) { Value = value2 });
   batch.BatchCommands.Add(batchcommand);
   batch.Prepare();
   var reader = batch.ExecuteReader();
   reader.Close();
   batch.Dispose();
```

Comment: It is a `npgsql` issue and it is already fixed in 8.0.1 and is already out. So if you upgrade your `Npgsql` it should be fixed. But I couldn't relate your issue with the linked issue. In the linked issue the problem is having parameter names case-insensitive but you have distinct parameter names

Comment: @Eldar thanks that fixed it I didn't realise i needed both

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade npgsql to 8.0.1 as well